# ~ operator in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, geopackage

I'm running this part of a query on Postgres and it's running fine

```
where column ~ '^[0-9]'
```

But when I try to run it in SQLite, I get this error:

> near "~": syntax error

Do you have any idea how I can run this function in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you want columns that start with a digit, you can simply use:

```
where substr(column, 1, 1) between '0' and '9'
```

SQLite doesn't have native support for regular expressions -- although it is really easy to extend.  It does use support Unix globbing, but in this case you can use the built-in functions.

Comment: It worked. Can you explain me why you add  (...1,1) on the substr function? 
Thanks!

Comment: @J.Patordi . . . Because `substr(column)` will return the error "
wrong number of arguments to function substr()".  Those arguments return the first character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators) operator:

```
WHERE column GLOB '[0-9]*'
```

`[0-9]` means that the value starts with a numeric digit and `*` means that may follow any character(s).